# data structure with insertion of O(logn) and O(k) for first k Largest elements

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, time-complexity

I have been asked in data structure class to find a data structure that fits those needs :

```
Insert(S,num) - Insert to S a num in a O(log(n)) complexion time

PrintMax_k(S) - Print the k (constant) first biggest elemnts in some order(doesnt matter) in a O(k) complexion time

PrintAll(S) - Print all elemnts in some order(doesnt matter) in a O(n) complexion time
```

what type of data structure do I need to utilize?

Comment: I thought about it, but how I will I know whos the first k biggest elements?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

Comment: Is `k` known when you start building the list? Or are you expected to answer for any given value of `k` at any time?

Answer (score 0):

As *k* is assumed to be a constant, you could create this datastructure as a combination of a min heap `H` with at most *k* elements (implemented in an array data structure), and a standard array `A` with the remaining elements (if any) in any order.

The operations would be as follows:

```py
Insert(S,num): 
    if size(H) < k:
        H.insert(num)
    else if H[0] < num: # compare with root value of heap, which is its minimum, at index 0
        A.append(H[0])
        H[0] := num # replace root value
        H.heapify() # sift down num, so heap property is restored
   else:
        A.append(num)
```

For the implementation of a heap's insert and heapify methods, see [Binary Heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Insert) on Wikipedia, or elsewhere.

After any call of `Insert`, `H` will have the *k*-greatest values inserted so far. Any overflow (smaller values) will be in `A`.

```py
PrintMax_k(S):
    for i in 0..size(H)-1: # simply iterate over the heap (which is an array)
        print H[i]
```

Finally:

```py
PrintAll(S):
    PrintMax_k(S) # call the above function
    for i in 0..size(A)-1:
        print A[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Balanced Binary Search Tree Implementation for adding /Deleting /Finding Particular value in [Balanced Binary Search Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)

Balanced Binary Search Tree is/can be implemented in most of the all popular language
`C++ has set,map etc.`
`Java has HashMap,TreeSet etc.` They also comes with functions to add/delete/print/ etc.

If you implement your own BBST,
For printing First K max in O(k):

You can do it like this:

```
print(node,K):
    if(K<=0)return
    if(sizeof(node)<=K){
       Do a In order DFS Traversal From this node
       return
    }
    else if(sizeof(node)>K){
        if(sizeof(node->left)<=K){
           print(node-left,sizeof(node->left))
           print(node->right,K-sizeof(node-left))
        }
        else{
            print(node->left,K)
        }
    }
```

How to get the size of a node? You can add a parameter to store this size of it's subtree and update it accordingly after a Adding/Deleting a value

For `Print_all` just pass sizeof(Root) as the parameter K in print function